# eclipse-CDT won't debug my c++ programs

Tags: programming, c++, eclipse-cdt

I've installed eclipse from ubuntu repositories and I installed CDT from "install new software."

But every time I try to debug a simple program, an error occurs that says 'launching q.cpp debug' encountered a problem    "Program file does not exist"

Also there is nothing in Run > Debug As.

What should I do?

When I type commands, the eclipse command corrector (I don't know what it is called) doesn't show me any any commands to help me to choose the correct one.

Comment: Did you ever get this question resolved?  If you solved it your self can you provide the answer.  If it is still unresolved can you edit the question and improve it so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `g++` as your compiler, you should compile your program with the `-g -O0` flags, to facilitate debugging.